# Can't animate modal on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm currently creating my custom implementation of a modal. All works perfectly fine so far but I can't seem to animate it and I can't get my head around it.

This is my Modal component

```
 import React from 'react'
import Slider from './Slider'
import {IoIosCloseCircleOutline} from "react-icons/io"
import styled from "styled-components";



export default function Modal(props) {

    const Modal = styled.div `
    transform: translateX(${({animateSlideInRight}) => (animateSlideInRight ? "0" : "100vw")});
    transition: transform 1s;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 650px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    transition: all 1.1s ease-out;
    box-shadow: 
      -2rem 2rem 2rem rgba(black, 0.2);
    visibility: visible;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    `

    const closeModal = () => {
        props.setShow(false)
    }

    const data = props.data
    if (!props.show) {
        return null
    }
    return (
        <div className="modalWrapper">  
            <Modal className="modal" id="modal" animateSlideInRight = {props.show}>
                <div className="modalHeaderWrapper">
                <IoIosCloseCircleOutline className="modalCloseCross" onClick={closeModal}/>
                    <img src={data[0].logo} alt="logo" />
                    <h2>{data[0].title}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="modalRightFlex">
                    <Slider 
                        images={[data[0].image1Carrousel, data[0].image2Carrousel, data[0].image3Carrousel]}
                    />
                    <div className="modalRightDescription">
                        <h1>Description</h1>
                        <p>{data[0].description}</p>
                        <h1>Technologies</h1>
                        <div className="modalTechnologiesWrapper">
                            {data[0].technologiesUsed.map((image) => {
                                return <img src={image}/>
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you see my modal is a `styledComponent` that defines whether to translate in X or not depending on the show state. In my scenario I had to lift up state since I'm opening this modal from clicking on a card which in itself is a different component, so their ancestor is taking care of the states.

My current CSS for modal is as seen in the styled div.

**Things I have tried**

1-tried having a regular div and handle the animation through CSS with keyframes --> It works for sliding in but it doesn't when I close (in that instance I had my show state defining a class name for the modal with a different animation for each of them)

2-tried to set a animate state and define the `className` based on whether that state is true or false. It works the first time when I close (despite having to introduce a timeout of the animation duration between setting animate to false and show to false) but then it goes bonkers and starts flickering everywhere.

Anyway someone can see the issue? Many thanks

**edit**
Sanbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-shape-vxujw

Comment: Next time please provide a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), CSS question, in particular, should have a live example to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `Modal` in the outer scope of the component rendering it, the animation does not complete and you resetting it by redefining it on the next render.

Also resetting an animation should be done with `none` instead of giving an actual length.

Moreover, there might be more CSS bugs related that can hide your `modal` animation like `z-index` and `position`, if your question is focused on an animation problem you should remove all the noise around it.

See working example:

```
const Animation = styled.div`
  transform: ${({ animate }) => (animate ? "none" : "translateX(500px)")};
  transition: transform 1s;
`;

function Modal(props) {
  return <Animation animate={props.show}>hello</Animation>;
}

function Component() {
  const [show, toggle] = useReducer((p) => !p, false);
  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} />
      <button onClick={toggle}>show</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, you shouldn't return `null` when you don't want to animate, you will lose the close animation.

```
// remove this code
if (!props.show) {
  return null;
}
```

[image: Edit Q-65422582-AnimateTransition]

Comment: I think you've forgotten to add the ```transition``` property for the styled component. Currently there's no animation in the sandbox you provided (the element's position changes directly without any transition).

Comment: Will try to implement this now if it doesn't work I'll create a sandbox

Comment: @DennisVash I have implemented your solution (or I think I did but still not working) included sandbox link in the question as an edit

Comment: Again, remove unnessery noise when asking about a specific topic, you returning `null` when `show` is `false`, which won't cause an animation because you render nothing. See https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-moon-w9lz0?file=/src/Modal.js

Comment: I see where I was going wrong. Thanks for the answer and the advice